# To find the square root of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

My question is:

Find the value of $k$ such that $$4x^6 - 24x^5 + 20x^4 + 68x^3 -44x^2 - 40x + k$$ is a perfect square.

hey all i have made an edit. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Any help to solve this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is incomplete: there is no value of $k$ that makes the polynomial *identically* equal to $0$, and there are infinitely many values of $k$ that make it equal to $0$ for *some* $x$.

Comment: -1 question doesn't make scene

Comment: I presume (based on the question's title) that the goal is to find $k$ such that the polynomial is a perfect square (with integer coefficients). The "$=0$" part is irrelevant.

Comment: @meg_1997: Note that all the coefficients we are given are divisible by the square $4$. Divide by $4$. It will make the coefficients pleasantly smaller.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I had thought that too, at first. As it turns out, though, the required $k$ is *not* divisible by $4$.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It would be worth it to me to have the arithmetic simpler when calculating the early coefficients.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the goal is to find $k$ so that the polynomial is a perfect square, start by noting that it must be the square of a cubic polynomial:

$$4x^6 - 24x^5 + 20x^4 + 68x^3 -44x^2 - 40x + k=(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)^2\;.$$

Clearly this immediately require that $a=2$. Now the square of $(2x^3+bx^2+cx+d)^2$ is

$$4x^6+4bx^5+(4c+b^2)x^4+(4d+2bc)x^3+(2bd+c^2)x^2+2cdx+d^2\;,$$

so you have the following system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&4b=-24\\
&4c+b^2=20\\
&4d+2bc=68\\
&2bd+c^2=-44\\
&2cd=-40\\
&d^2=k
\end{align*}\right.$$

Clearly $b=-6$; the second equation then allows you to find $c$, and you can then use the third, fourth, or fifth to find $d$ and then $k$. (To play safe, you should verify that the third, fourth, and fifth equations all yield the same value of $d$.)

Comment: Beat me to it. (I shouldn't've spent time commenting this interpretation of the question!) :)

Comment: @DayLateDon: Well, it *was* the only interpretation that made much sense, given the title! (And the fact that the numbers work out so nicely makes it even more likely, I think.)